# assign observations into hours python

Tags: python, count, pandas-groupby, resampling

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
start                  end                   city
2010-08-08 20:05:00 2010-08-08 22:05:00      NY
2010-08-08 21:05:00 2010-08-08 21:35:00      NY
2010-08-09 08:05:00 2010-08-08 08:55:00      SF
```

I need to receive the dataframe, which would count, per city, how many times there is an observation in each hour. For example, for NY it would give 1 in hour 20 on date 2010-08-08, 1 in hour 21 on the same date, and 1 in hour 22. Sometimes "start" and "end" happens in the same hour, sometimes in different hours. So, for the example, I would get:

```
hour               city   count
2010-08-08 20       NY     1
2010-08-08 21       NY     2
2010-08-08 22       NY     1
2010-08-09 08       SF     1
```

I tried to do it with "resample", but it does not account for the duration, for the difference between start and end.

Thanks a lot for your help.